# What is the good way to remove SDK and other soft?

Tags: ati, software-installation, install-from-source

I have installed `AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9` using install script:

```
./Install-AMD-APP.sh
```

Everything is ok and here is the installation log:

```
1) Starting Installation of AMD APPSDK v2.9 ....
2) 64-bit Operating System Found...
3) Version Information Available in VersionInfo.txt
4) Untar command executed succesfully, The SDK package available
5) Untar command executed succesfully, The ICD package available 
6) SDK Binaries/Source/Samples/Other files copying to  = /opt/AMDAPP
7) SDK files copied successfully at /opt/AMDAPP/
8) Copying the OpenCL runtime files to System...
9) Updating Environment variables...
10) Updating LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /etc/profile
11) Environment variables updated successfully
12) Initialize global environment variables...
13) Global environment variables Initialized
14) AMD APP installation Completed
15) Reboot required to reflect the changes
```

So, I understand it as follows: binary files are copied to `/opt/AMDAPP/` folder, some env variables are set and so on.

I'm wondering, how to remove this SDK?

Should I just remove `/opt/AMDAPP/` folder and destroy `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?
Or I should do some extra things?

I mean how to remove installed software not via `dpkg` from my system in general and in this case in particularly.

Comment: Is there any uninstallation script?

Comment: @Avinash Raj, No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uninstall APP SDK components on linux systems:

1. Delete the directory pointed to the `AMDAPPSDKROOT` environment variable.
2. Remove the `AMDAPPSDKROOT` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables.
3. Delete the `amdocl[32]64].so` from `/etc/OpenCL/vendors`.
4. Manually remove temporary and new files created with OpenCL.

Unless otherwise modified at install, the main files would have been installed to `/opt/AMDAPP`.

Source: [AMD APP SDK v2.9 Installation Notes](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2013/07/AMD_APP_SDK_Installation_Notes.pdf)